# WiX Burn variable that returns folder name where it is ran?

Tags: wix, burn

Is there a WiX Burn variable that would return the folder name where the bundle is being ran?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WiX manual has a complete list of the [built-in Burn variables](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/bundle_built_in_variables.htm). In this case, the closest variable you'll find is the `WixBundleOriginalSource` variable. That will also contain the name of the bundle executable. You'd obviously need to do a little custom work to trim off the file name to get the folder.

Comment: Is it possible to do this trimming within Burn?  I have an MsiPackage that I need to call passing it the full path of an INI file that's located in the WiXBundleOriginalSoruce variable.  I'm trying not to transform the MSI to do the parsing there.